# How to combine two lists in a single foreach loop in C# ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two objects

- `List<string> ids;`
- `List<string> names;`

Both have same lentgh/size.

I want to display them as hyperlinks in a foreach loop. I have tried to control the index of names list using an integer iteration on each step.

```
int i = 0;
foreach (string id in ids)
{
    body.InnerHtml += "<h2><a href='go.aspx?id=" + id + "'>"+ names[i++] +"</a></h2>";
}
```

This works well, but is there any better way?

Comment: are you asking how to do this explicitly `in a foreach loop`, as suggested by your question?

Comment: A better way would be to have a list of Tuple<string, string> with value one being the id and two being the name. If these two things belong together, put them together. Consider making a simple class holding ID and name: class Thing {string id, string name} and making a list of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Enumerable.Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). That's what it's meant for.

```
foreach (var item in ids.Zip(names, (id, name) => new { id, name }))
{
    body.InnerHtml += "<h2><a href='go.aspx?id=" + item.id + "'>" + item.name + "</a></h2>";
}
```

Also I recommend [StringBuilder](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html) for string concatenation in the loop.

If you need to access some fields together, they should probably be located together. I mean create a new class and store them together.

```
class MyItem
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Then use `List<MyItem>`. If you were doing this, you shouldn't have had this question in first place :)

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to use a `foreach` loop, make a new collection with LINQ ([Zip extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) and iterate over that:

```
var combined = ids.Zip(names, (id, name) => new { id = id, name = name  });

foreach(var c in combined) 
{
    body.InnerHtml += "<h2><a href='go.aspx?id=" + c.id + "'>"+ c.name +"</a></h2>"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibly solution is to use Linq's Zip function:

```
const string link = "<h2><a href='go.aspx?id={0}'>{1}</a></h2>";
body.InnerHtml += String.Concat(
                        ids.Zip(names, (id, name) => String.Format(link, id, name)));
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `const` here - could cause unnecessary version problems via compiler propagation to dependent code (if the string pattern ever changes).

Comment: @kaveman The const will be private so it won't cause such problems, since it can't be referenced outside the assembly.

Comment: This changes the behavior of OP's code. You forgot about `InnerHtml` value that may exist, you're overwriting it. You should be appending it.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes I thought about that. And if there is any existing values in `body.InnerHtml` a `+=` would solve that problem.

Comment: @MatthewWatson good point! It would likely be private...I guess the keyword just stands out and makes me stop and think for a second.

Comment: Please add it in your answer. Btw I like the way you made the code cleaner with `String.Format` +1.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach is to use a for loop with a total count. E.g.:

```
int totalCount = listOfStringsA.Count + listOfStringsB.Count;
for (int count=0; count < totalCount; count++)
{
    string item = null;
    if (count < totalCount) item = listOfStringsA[count];
    else                    item = listOfStringsB[count - totalCount];
    // do whatever with item ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not use a `for` loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i < ids.Count; i++)
{
   body.InnerHtml += "<h2><a href='go.aspx?id=" + ids[i] + "'>"+ names[i] +"</a></h2>"
}
```